# How to block file and folder creation in Legacy filter driver for windows

Tags: c, windows, filter-driver

I am trying to create a legacy filter driver for windows to block the "creation of file and folder" in external storage devices.

I tried with the following code

```
if( lDeviceType==cwUSBDRIVE || lDeviceType==cwEXTERNALHDD)
{
  if(irpSp->MajorFunction==IRP_MJ_CREATE)
  {
   if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options)&FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE)
    {
            Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;//Deny Access
        Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
   else if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options)&FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE)
   {

        Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;//Deny Access
        Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
         return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;

   }
  }
}
```

while working with the code it block's the file/folder creation. But it also block's file copying from device and file opening operations.

I need to block the creation of file\folder and allow the copying from the device and opening the files.

Comment: I removed the [tag:c] tag, but this was a mere guess. Please tag the language you're actually using, if it's C, replace the C++ tag with C.

Comment: File copying implies file creation, so if file creation is blocked it makes sense that copying is also blocked.

Comment: @Felix Palment: thanks for the update, code is created in C. Removed C++ tag

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: Thanks for update but is there any alternative solution? As its a requirement in my project

Comment: but copy file include creation new file. because this it and blocked. and impossible determinate by what reason created new file - for copy some content from another file or by some another

Comment: @RbMm before checking the  IRP we are checking the device type. The above code is only executed for external device

Comment: and so what ? how this related to copy files/ block creation ?

Comment: @RbMm Why would copying a file **from** the device require to **create** a file on that device? That file should be created in the destination folder.

Comment: but need open file for copy. you block any file open

Comment: @RbMm, while commenting the above code. the file copying and open operations are working

Comment: i complete not understand what is "working" for you. how i view you block any file open

Comment: @RbMm while  removing the above code then copying and file opening is working.but while using the code  its not working

Comment: you block file open. so what you want ?

Comment: @RbMm I need to block only file/folder creation

Comment: @RbMm So,  **Is it possible to allow open and disable create options for files/folders** ?

Comment: of course yes. you need look for `CreateDisposition` parameter: [`CreateDisposition = IrpSp->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24;`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L764) - if it `FILE_OPEN` - allow, otherwise disable

Comment: OK. can you please mention Createdispostion datatype

Comment: what is data type ? simply int. i show you example from fastfat. `CreateDisposition` this is exactly parameter from `IoCreateFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, @RbMm.
This issue was solved using CREATE DISPOSITION. Below I am posting the code that I used to solve this issue. As a reference to others,

```
              if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options)&FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE)
                   {
                       if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) == FILE_CREATE)
                       {
                           Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;//Deny Access
                           Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                           IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
                           return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                       }
                   }
                   else if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options)&FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE)
                   {
                       if((irpSp->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) == FILE_CREATE)
                       {
                           Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;//Deny Access
                           Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                           IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
                           return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                       }
            }
```

Comment: usually you need compare with `FILE_OPEN` and allow only this option, else another deny. say instead `FILE_CREATE` disposition we can use `FILE_OPEN_IF` - if file not exist - both disposition will have same effect. can be used `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF` and so on